# Javascript “confirm” in IE6 and IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why doesn't this code work in IE6 or IE7?

```
$('a').click(
    function()
    {
        var urlIsExternal = true;

        var urlMedicareDir = '/medicare/';
        var urlMedicareHost = 'health.healthcare.com';
        var urlMedicare = 'https://' + urlMedicareHost + urlMedicareDir;

        var urlAppsHost = 'apps.healthcare.com';

        var urlCurrent = String( window.location );
        var urlCurrentPrefix = urlCurrent.substring( 0, urlMedicare.length );
        var urlCurrentURL = $.url( urlCurrent );

        var urlClicked = $(this).attr('href');
        var urlClickedURL = $.url( $(this).attr('href') );

        var urlHost = urlClickedURL.attr('host');

        if( !urlHost.length )
        {
            urlHost = urlCurrentURL.attr('host');
        }

        var urlConfirmMessage = 'You are now leaving the Medicare website.';

        if( urlCurrentPrefix == urlMedicare )
        {
            if( urlClicked.substring( 0, 1 ) == '/' ) // starts with slash
            {
                if( urlClicked.substring( 0, urlMedicareDir.length ) == urlMedicareDir )
                {
                    urlIsExternal = false;
                }
            }

            if( urlClicked.substring( 0, urlMedicare.length ) == urlMedicare )
            {
                urlIsExternal = false;
            }

            if (
                urlClicked.substring( 0, 1 ) != '/' &&
                urlClicked.substring( 0, 4 ) != 'http' &&
                urlClicked.substring( 0, 4 ) != 'file'
            )
            {
                urlIsExternal = false;
            }

            if( urlAppsHost == urlHost )
            {
                urlIsExternal = false;
            }

            if( urlClicked.substring(urlClicked.length-4) == '.pdf' )
            {
                urlIsExternal = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            urlIsExternal = false;
        }

        if( urlIsExternal )
        {
            if( confirm( urlConfirmMessage ) )
            {
                window.open( urlClicked );
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```

For some reason when the links are clicked in IE6 or IE7, they do not direct the user to the link and it does not prompt a confirm dialog. It should prompt a confirm dialog, but for some reason, it is not.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the error console?

Comment: Code tip: Don't `String( window.location )` but rather `window.location.href`.

Comment: It would help everyone (including you!) if you could narrow down the problem to the smallest case possible. Try inserting a handful of meaningful `alert()` calls in at key points in the code, to make sure they're getting executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're preventing the default action of the anchor ("a").

You should start `$('a').click( function( event ) {` so that when you get here:

```
if( urlIsExternal ) {

   // This tells jQuery to NOT follow the hyperlink
   event.preventDefault(); 

   if( confirm( urlConfirmMessage ) ) {
      window.open( urlClicked );  
   }

}
```

However, what's really missing is that this code needs to run ***after*** the document has loaded. So you just need to wrap your function with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a').click( function( event ) {
      /* your code */
   }
});
```

Without the call to `$(document).ready()`, the JavaScript runs before the body of the document is rendered, so it doesn't find any `<a>` tags to which it can attach the click event.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if the user clicks on a link that has an href  starting with some value other than the current host, you want offer a confirm dialog. That is a realy annoying strategy, why doesn't the user know **before** clicking on the link that it wil take them elsewhere?

Anyway, a simple version of what you are trying to do is:

```
function showPrompt() {
  return confirm('Do you really want to leaving ' + window.location.host +
                 '?\nPress OK to continue or Cancel to stay on this page.');
}

window.onload = function() {

  // The links collection is live and available as a property of window
  var link, links = document.links;

  // Include criteria for host, hostName, protocol, whatever as required
  var re = new RegExp(window.location.host || 'no host');

  for (var i=0, iLen=links.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    link = links[i];

    // Only add the listener to links that need it
    if (!re.test(link.href)) {

      // Add the listener however you want, this way is simple and robust
      link.onclick = showPrompt;
    }
  }
}
```